# Insert unicode value into sqlite from python code

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

I have the following query for inserting values into sqlite3 db, which is made in python code;

```
insert into 'SplCharTest' ('Id','name','address','telefon') values (1.0, u'cust01', u'addr01  strasse 48908', 2131234213.0)
```

I am getting the following error when I try to execute this query;

```
sqlite3CursorObj.execute(dataInsertQueryForSheet)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'cust01'": syntax error
```

I noticed that the presence of u (unicode) in front of 'cust01' is making the problem. Could anybody please tell me how to insert unicode value into sqlite db. Simple usage of 'str' is not possible as I am getting the unicode values from an excel file using openpyxl package and there could be special characters.

Below given is my python code

```
dataInsertQueryForSheet = "insert into '"+tableNameForSheet+"' ("+columnNamesCSV+") values (%s)" % unicode(rowDataList)[1:(rowDataStrLen-1)]
sqlite3CursorObj.execute(dataInsertQueryForSheet)
```

Here variable `tableNameForSheet` contains the table name, `columnNamesCSV` contains all the columns names in CSV format and `rowDataList` contains all values to be inserted as an array list.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't want to to use floats for telephone numbers especially since [sqlite will give at least 16 digits in an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261220/storing-currency-values-in-sqlite3/3261239#3261239)]. Better still, use text type as there is nothing numerical about phone numbers (except for them being strings of digits).

Comment: @msw - Thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite always uses Unicode.

The easiest way to use strings while avoiding formatting problems or SQL injection attacks is to use parameters:

```
sql = "insert into "+tableNameForSheet+" ("+columnNamesCSV+") values (?,?,?,?)"
parameters = [1, u'cust01', u'addr01  strasse 48908', "2131234213"]
cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
```